Nautilus doesn't show safely remove option
I cannot see the 'Safely Remove' button in the right-click options of Nautilus. The 'Eject' option does not power off the disk, and my hard drive is still running. I can use the Disks app to do this, but before I upgraded my system from 22.04 to 24.04, it was possible to do this in Nautilus as well.

After clicking 'Eject' or the Eject icon, the disk disappears from Nautilus, but I can still see the LED on the disk and hear that it is still working. The drive continues to work until I press the power off button in the Disks app.

After this, the drive stops and shuts down safely.
What is wrong? I do not have anything installed?

I don't see this problem on my freshly installed Ubuntu 24.04. I see the Freshly remove option in the context menu.

Upgrade to Ubuntu 24.10 fixed the problem.
